# Encoding an SHA-1 string based on post variables

Tags: php, post, http-post, sha

I'm trying to find a service that will allow me to POST to that will return an SHA-1 encoded string based off of the variables that I pass to it.

I haven't been able to find one so I've thought about writing my own PHP solution.

If I end up going this route, is there a specific best practice in PHP for creating SHA-1 stings?

Comment: Have you checked the manual?? http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php

Comment: The services that I've tried all return the full HTML of the page, just wondering if anyone knows of anything off the top of their head before I go and build the page myself.

Comment: what would be wrong with: `$hash = sha1($someVar);`?

Comment: If you think about it, your service can be just one input with a value, then POST and use `sha1` and return a string, or am I missing something here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [sha1()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php):

> sha1 — Calculate the sha1 hash of a string

**An example:**

```
<?php
$str = 'apple';

if (sha1($str) === 'd0be2dc421be4fcd0172e5afceea3970e2f3d940') {
    echo "Would you like a green or red apple?";
}
?>
```

(source: [sha1() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php))

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from the php manual

```
$str = 'apple';

if (sha1($str) === 'd0be2dc421be4fcd0172e5afceea3970e2f3d940') {
    echo "Would you like a green or red apple?";
}
```